# Scala pattern matching with async (or any monad) guards

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, monads, future, scala-cats

Today I came across the following problem:
I had some pattern matching going on, **simplified** looking like this:

```
object Sync {
  sealed trait MatchType
  case object BigType extends MatchType
  case object SmallType extends MatchType
  case object EvenType extends MatchType
  case object UnknownType extends MatchType

  def syncPatternMatch(i: Int): MatchType = i match {
    case _ if i > 100 => BigType
    case _ if i < 3 => SmallType
    case _ if i % 2 == 0 => EvenType
    case _ => UnknownType
  }
}
```

Now unfortunately I figured out, that my guards/extractors will be `Future[Boolean]`. Imagine they call an external web service to get the result.
Obviously I cant use the guard or extractor pattern with a Future (or any monad).

So now I want to check each condition asynchronously, but break on the first successful one.

Basically I want the opposite of normal monadic flow – meaning stopping on the first success.
My implementation seems to work well, but I am curios to see if there is an easier way or what kind of pattern you would use in this case.

Remember that my example is extremely simple for the sake of being an example.

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Async {
  sealed trait MatchType
  case object BigType extends MatchType
  case object SmallType extends MatchType
  case object EvenType extends MatchType
  case object UnknownType extends MatchType

  type Match[B] = EitherT[Future, MatchType, B]
  def isBigEnough(i: Int): Match[Unit] = Future(if(i > 100) Left(BigType) else Right(()))
  def isVerySmall(i: Int): Match[Unit] = Future(if(i < 3) Left(SmallType) else Right(()))
  def isEven(i: Int): Match[Unit] = Future(if(i % 2 == 0) Left(EvenType) else Right(()))
  def otherwise: Match[MatchType] = Future.successful(Right(UnknownType))

  implicit def liftFutureEither[A, B](f: Future[Either[A, B]]): EitherT[Future, A, B] = EitherT(f)
  implicit def extractFutureEither[A, B](e: EitherT[Future, A, B]): Future[Either[A, B]] = e.value

  def asyncPatternMatch(i: Int): Match[MatchType] =  for {
    _ <- isBigEnough(i)
    _ <- isVerySmall(i)
    _ <- isEven(i)
    default <- otherwise
  } yield default

  asyncPatternMatch(10).foreach(either => println(either.fold(identity, identity)))
  // EvenType
}
```

(btw. it is scala 2.12)
I would be happy for suggestions :)

Comment: I think you have factored too far. Try `def asyncPatternMatch(i: Future[Int]): Match[MatchType] = i.map(syncPatternMatch)`.

Comment: Mh my guards are asynchronous, imagine `isBigEnough` is calling an external api to get the result.
Don't really see how an `Future[Int]` as input would help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a 'monadic if' like [the cats one](http://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Monad.html#ifM[B](fa:F[Boolean])(ifTrue:=>F[B],ifFalse:=>F[B]):F[B]). We can actually roll a simplified version specifically for `Future`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait MatchType
object MatchType {
  case object Big extends MatchType
  case object Small extends MatchType
  case object Even extends MatchType
  case object Unknown extends MatchType

  def isBigEnough(i: Int): Future[Boolean] = Future successful (i > 100)
  def isVerySmall(i: Int): Future[Boolean] = Future successful (i < 3)
  def isEven(i: Int): Future[Boolean] = Future successful (i % 2 == 0)

  def ifFuture[A](
    test: Future[Boolean],
    trueCase: => A,
    falseCase: => Future[A]): Future[A] =
    test flatMap { t =>
      if (t) Future successful trueCase else falseCase
    }

  def apply(i: Int): Future[MatchType] =
    ifFuture(isBigEnough(i), Big,
    ifFuture(isVerySmall(i), Small,
    ifFuture(isEven(i), Even,
    Future successful Unknown)))
}
```

Comment: @rincewind you're welcome. `ifM` is just a monadic combinator, which reminds me that I could have actually implemented it much more simply. Updating my answer.